# error on mysql-workbench "(" is not valid at this position, expecting EOF, ";"

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I use MySql Workbench, when I write the "partition by" clause like this. It always shows the error:

> "(" is not valid at this position, expecting EOF, ";"

this query is ok when I write online, so please show me how to fix this error on MySQL workbench

```
SELECT DISTINCT IF(IsActive = 0, 'Inactive', EmpName) EmpName, 
SUM(SaleAmount) OVER 
  (PARTITION BY IF(IsActive = 0, 'Inactive', EmpName)) [SaleAmount]
FROM tbl_sales
```

Thanks pro...

Comment: You have already a sales amount column, and then why you decided to call the result of your window function as [saleAmount]. Just remove those square brackets, and/or give another name. If error persists, then you need to focus your attention on somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Usually that type of error refers to some sort of syntax error. I won't swear by it cause i dont have much experience with partition and IF statements like that, but maybe just take out the [] around SaleAmount? When i ran it in mysql, it gave me an error for those brackets, but after i took them out it only gave me an error cause that table doesn't exist in my database